# Why is the data from the database not displayed in the select through ajax?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

Good evening, I'm sorry, this text was translated through google translator
I'm not very good at parsing javascript, when I copy this code from the documentation, the data is successfully loaded and displayed

```
$("#select-repo").selectize({
  valueField: "url",
  labelField: "name",
  searchField: "name",
  create: false,
  render: {
    option: function (item, escape) {
      return (
        "<div>" +
        '<span class="title">' +
        '<span class="name"><i class="icon ' +
        (item.fork ? "fork" : "source") +
        '"></i>' +
        escape(item.name) +
        "</span>" +
        '<span class="by">' +
        escape(item.username) +
        "</span>" +
        "</span>" +
        '<span class="description">' +
        escape(item.description) +
        "</span>" +
        '<ul class="meta">' +
        (item.language ? '<li class="language">' + escape(item.language) + "</li>" : "") +
        '<li class="watchers"><span>' +
        escape(item.watchers) +
        "</span> watchers</li>" +
        '<li class="forks"><span>' +
        escape(item.forks) +
        "</span> forks</li>" +
        '<li class="stars"><span>' +
        escape(item.followers) +
        "</span> stars</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>"
      );
    },
  },
  score: function (search) {
    var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
    return function (item) {
      return score(item) * (1 + Math.min(item.watchers / 100, 1));
    };
  },
  load: function (query, callback) {
    if (!query.length) return callback();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/" + encodeURIComponent(query),
      type: "GET",
      error: function () {
        callback();
      },
      success: function (res) {
        callback(res.repositories.slice(0, 10));
      },
    });
  },
});
```

But as soon as I change the data to my own, my code stops working

```
$(".add-items-select").selectize({
    valueField: "id",
    labelField: "name",
    // searchField: "name",
    create: true,
    render: {
      option: function (item, escape) {
        return "<div>" + '<span class="title">' + escape(item.id) + "</span>" + "</div>";
      },
    },
    load: function (query, callback) {
      if (!query.length) return callback();
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/warehouse/api/products/" + encodeURIComponent(query)+ "/?format=json",
        type: "GET",
        error: function () {
          callback();
        },
        success: function (res) {
          callback(res);
          callback(console.log(res));
        },
      });
    },
  });
```

Data is displayed in the console, but the render function does not work
Here is my json

```
{"id":1,"company_detail":{"id":1,"name":"test","adress":null},"articul":"1","name":"teyit","category_detail":null,"stock":0,"sell_price":"123.00","last_buy_price":"1.00","archived":false}
```

Comment: Your JSON should be an array of objects, not a single object.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought about this for almost 2 days, removing the code "encodeURIComponent(query)" my code WORKED